# chai.request attach files array

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, chai

I'm writing a generic test function with chai.request, here is what I have:

```
//this is in some function
    var file = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/../test/files/' + args.fileName);
    chai.request(server)
            .post('/v2')
            .field('email', args.email)
            .field('subject', args.subject)
            .attach('fileName', file, args.fileName)
            .end((err, res) => {
                //some test conditions

                done();
            });
```

This works great if there is only 1 file passed, the problem is that sometimes I need to pass in an array of files, but I have no idea how to attach those when I'm not sure of the number of files coming in.

**PS:** Some tests require having more than one file passed in at the same time, so simply looping though the entire thing twice will not work, I have to somehow loop through the .attach part only.

Comment: Without more context I would suggest just making your test simpler. Have 1 test for a single file and then another for multiple files.

Comment: I can do that, but I still have no idea how to loop through this and attach each file to the request for the second test.

Comment: You would know how many files are being passed in for the second test so you would just hard code it. I'm sure there is a way to generalize it...this is just the quick and dirty to get you going.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem when writing tests for an application I'm working on and this is the only question I've found on the issue and nothing in the documentation either.

The solution that worked for me was to append `.n` to the fieldname like so:

```
chai.request(server)
    .post('/v2')
    .field('email', args.email)
    .field('subject', args.subject)
    .attach('fileName.0', file, args.fileName)
    .attach('fileName.1', file1, args.fileName1)
    .attach('fileName.2', file2, args.fileName2)
    .end((err, res) => {
        //some test conditions
        done();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine files, array of files, and regular fields like so

```js
const agent = chai.request.agent(app); // app is the express server
let postAgent = agent.post('/api/post')
     .field({'field1':val1, 'field2': val2, ...})
     .attach('media', './image.png');
const array_of_files = ['./image2.jpg', './image3.png']; // array of files to send
for (let i = 0; i < array_of_files.length; ++i) {
   postAgent = postAgent.attach(`media_array`, array_of_files[i]); // populates array of fields in 'media_array' of form-data
}
postAgent.then((res) => {
   // your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to tackle this issue I found was the following:

```
const fileCount = 10
let req = chai.request(app).post(`${baseUrl}/upload`)

Array.from(new Array(fileCount)).forEach((_, index) => {
  req = req.attach('files', Buffer.from(''), `file-${index}.png`)
})

const response = await req
```